# Visualforce: calling method as an action inside conditional statement

Tags: visualforce, redirect, conditional

This is working code, saying that Telemarketing users are routed to a standard New Event page, while other users are redirected to `MyPage`:

```
action="{!if($Profile.Name !='Telemarketing', urlFor($Page.MyPage), urlFor($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, null, true))}"/>
```

Instead of redirecting to `MyPage`, I have to call a method inside a controller. How do I do that?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
action="{!if($Profile.Name !='Telemarketing', {!redirect}, urlFor($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, null, true))}"/>
```

This code is not working. I am trying to call `redirect` method inside a controller.

**Update1.** Full code, not working:

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="CTRL_EventRedirect" 
       action="{!if($Profile.Name !='Telemarketing', 
                    redirect, 
                    urlFor($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, null, true))}"/>
```

Getting `Save error: Unknown property 'EventStandardController.redirect'`
Also, I get error if I use `redirect()` instead of `redirect`

**Update2.** Controller code:

```
public with sharing class CTRL_EventRedirect{     
    public PageReference redirect(){
        //method body
    }
}
```

**Update3.** I found a workaround, but instead of finding a solution for Visualforce, I moved a logic to a controller.

Here's the page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="CTRL_EventRedirect" action="{!redirectByProfile}"/>
```

And the controller logic:

```
public PageReference redirectByProfile()
{   
        User currentUser = DAL_User.getCurrentUser();
        Profile telemarketingProfile = DAL_User.getTelemarketingProfile();
        if (currentUser.ProfileId == telemarketingProfile.Id)
        {           
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Event.SObjectType.getDescribe();
            PageReference createEventPage = new PageReference('/' + dsr.getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
            createEventPage.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
            return createEventPage;
        }
        else    
            return redirect();
```

}

Comment: You don't have to add a new `!`. Try `{redirect}` instead.

Comment: You do not need braces at all.

Comment: I'm getting save error if I don't use braces. Please check the updated post.

Comment: what is signature of redirect() method in controller?

Comment: public, non static

Comment: when faced with this issue, I've followed http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/overriding-a-page-for-some-but-not-all-users - especially the section in 'Discussion'. I'd like to think there is an easier answer (I tried a controller property of type ApexPages.Action which compiles but won't execute). see also - http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2008/11/14/redirecting-users-to-different-visualforce-pages/

Answer (score 1):

Use below,

```
   <apex:commandButton action="{!redirect}" rendered="{!$Profile.Name !='Telemarketing'}"/>

 <apex:commandButton action="{!urlFor($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, null, true)}" rendered="{!$Profile.Name =='Telemarketing'}"/>
```

Comment: I get "Unknown property 'EventStandardController.redirect'". I then use redirect(), getting save error again. Full code is here: <apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="CTRL_EventRedirect" action="{!if($Profile.Name !='Telemarketing', redirect, urlFor($Action.Event.NewEvent, null, null, true))}"/>

Comment: How have you defined your recirect method in controller. Can you display that part of code/Method?

Comment: Yes. I edited the post. Please check the Update2 part of it.

Comment: does it work if you use only action="{!redirect}" ? @justasd

Comment: Yes, in this case it works as expected.

Comment: I found a workaround. Please check the Update3 section of the post. And thanks.

Comment: hey @justasd, i too found a easy workaround, Please check and let me know.

Comment: hey @snehakem, yes, that's a good workaround and it works, but in this particular situation I'm coding the action for <apex:page>, not for <apex:commandButton>, so I can't have two <apex:page> elements in one VF page. But thanks a lot.